# Is Mole for Visual Studio by Karl Shifflett still active?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visualization, debuggervisualizer

I've been reading about [Mole](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/) and am interested in trying it but it doesn't look like it's being kept up to date as there's no mention in the documentation of Windows 7 or Visual Studio 2010. Is the project still active or is it now obsolete because there's a better alternative? Has anyone managed to get it working with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: December first and no Mole for Vs 2010. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's out for Visual Studio 2010 but it doesn't work in VS 2012. It hasn't been updated since June 2011. My feeling is the author(s) lost interest in working on it anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last week, Karl posted a [comment](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/portland-net-user-group-3-aug-2010-mole-2010/#comments) that Mole 2010 will be published in early November.

*Edit*: [Mole 2010](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/mole-2010-released/) has now (2011-02-23) been released, and appears to have a price tag of $50.